# Set up a SMTP server on CentOS

Tags: centos, smtp

I have a php script on a remote that is using PHPMailer in order to deliver mail.

I have now acquired a VPS, and I want it to act as SMTP server, so that `phpmailer` connects to this CentOS VPS and not `localhost`, in order to send the emails to the recipients.

Is that possible? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just setup and configure sendmail or another mailer.

Comment: that is actually a challenge. I just can't get any of these "mailers" working properly. postfix rejects the relay, sendmail refuses to accept connections on port 25 :(

Comment: sounds like you need to do a little more research and troubleshooting here.